Package name with username
Let's suppose there's a company abc that makes a library abc.
I'd like to make a Python package that interfaces with abc.
I could just call it abc. However, that seems selfish to take that name in case the company itself wants to publish a package using that name.
Alternatively, I could incorporate my username:
dharmatech_abc

Or:
dharmatech.abc

Question
If I go the username approach, which of the above is more idiomatic in Python packaging? Underscore or .?
If I decide to publish my package to pypi, and I went with the . approach, would the package be called dharmatech.abc?
If I go with the . approach, and I have other packages that also start with my username, will it be a problem that multiple separate packages all contribute to that dharmatech top level namespace?
Separate username package
One approach is to simply have a package dharmatech and have abc be in there.
The drawback to that approach is, I may want to similarly prefix dharmatech for other packages. And I may not want those packages to be in the same github repository. I.e. they would be in their own github repositories and be considered separate Python packages, although with the same module prefix.

I don't believe packages can have . in the name.  You could make a package named only dharmatech, that contains a module named abc.

Hey @JohnGordon ‍♂️ I added a section above Separate username package which goes into why I'm avoiding having a standalone dharmatech package. Basically, I'd like to keep projects under dharmatech as separate packages and github repositories.

The standard convention would probably be to name it python-abc, assuming interfaces in other languages could also be defined (rust-abc, haskell-abc, perl-abc, etc). Worry about conflicting with abc's plans when and if it comes up.

@chepner Why add the prefix python- if it's on PyPI? Isn't it implied that projects on PyPI are for Python?

I haven't posted to PyPI myself, but FWIW I found this from a quick search and it looks helpful: Are there any naming conventions for package names? - Discussions on Python.org which led to Names and normalization - Python Packaging User Guide

@wjandrea To me, anyway, the prefix would imply that it's the Python interface for the library, necessary but not sufficient for using abc.

@wjandrea The presence of https://pypi.org/project/cmake/ doesn't mean cmake is Python-only. ;-)

I believe that according to the convention the project should be named dharmatech-abc (with dash -), and the top-level import package dharmatech_abc (with underscore _).
I think you should have your own name first (or the name of your company, or any other name you make up), then the other company second. From what I have seen, companies do not like if you use their name first for your own software. We should read it like this: "this is dharmatech's library for abc".
The normalized form for distribution packages uses all lowercase and a single dash - as separator: python -m pip install dharmatech-abc.
The import package name should be a valid Python identifier of course, and the convention is all lowercase with a single underscore as separator: import dharmatech_abc.
Additionally you could consider packaging your project as a so-called namespace package, if you want to have multiple projects under the dharmatech umbrella. In this case the distribution package name would be the same (dharmatech-abc) but the import would look like this: import dharmatech.abc.

Great answer, thank you.
